# Can I change VM settings from local shell in ESXi 6.7?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have an ESXi 6.7u3 server which is running pfSense for my network. The problem is, I need to change this VMs network adapter, which connects the pfSense instance to the other VMs while bridged to a physical NIC for LAN.

So, if I power off the VM, I lose connectivity from LAN to the vmnic, other VMs and the management network.

I was hoping that I could do the change and it would be applied on next restart of the VM, but no. I think I also could reset the management network to the builtin NIC on the motherboard, but I had some issues getting the management interface back to the vmnic the last time, so I'd prefer to keep it as is.

Can I use `esxcli` to do this change locally?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to to power off your VM to change the network, you can do that while it's running.

But to be on the safe side, you can also do this:

- Enable the ESXi Shell

  - `Customize System` -> `Troubleshooting options` -> `Enable ESXi Shell`
- switch to the management console on the local console of the host (`alt`+`f1`)
- log in
- go to the VM directory

  ```
  cd /vmfs/volumes/datastore/vmname/
  ```
- get the VM World id and shutdown the VM

  ```
  esxcli vm process list
  esxcli vm process kill –type=[soft,hard,force] –world-id=<WorldID>
  ```
- make a backup of the .vmx file

  ```
  cp vmname.vmx vmname.vmx.bak
  ```
- Edit the .vmx file (vi is available)

  ```
  vi vmname.vmx
  ```
- start the VM

  ```
  vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms |grep vmname
  vim-cmd vmsvc/power.on <vmid>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the CLI info, I'll try this later today when I can afford some downtime! I tried to change the network on the fly, but I get this warning: `Failed to reconfigure virtual machine pfsense. The attempted operation cannot be performed in the current state (Powered on). `